# Unable to use DataNucleus enhancer without JDO annotations

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying DataNucleus with JDO api using only XML to define the persistence model, without adding annotation like @PersistenceCapable. That is something that supposedly supported by both JDO and DataNucleus, if I did understand both documentations.

For instance if I remove all annotations of Book.java, Inventory.java, Product.java in [datanucleus example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-samples/4.0/datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial-4.0-src.zip/download) and run `mvn clean compile` I should get the job done, because package.orm define those classes, but I get the following error for all this classes:

> (main) DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Class
>   org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Inventory was specified in
>   persistence-unit (maybe by not putting exclude-unlisted-classes)
>   Tutorial but not annotated, so ignoring
>
> ....
>
> (main) INFO  [DataNucleus.Enhancer] - DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 0 classes.

What I am missing?

Actual configuration files:

```
persistence.xml
...
<persistence-unit name="Tutorial">
    <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Inventory</class>
    <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Product</class>
    <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Book</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
...

package-h2.orm
<orm>
<package name="org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial">
    <!-- persistence-modifier is by default equal to: persistence-capable -->
    <class name="Inventory" table="INVENTORIES" >...</class>
    <class name="Product" table="PRODUCTS">...</class>
    <class name="Book" table="BOOKS">...</class>
</orm>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM metadata is to OVERRIDE JDO metadata. Consequently you need either annotations OR a JDO XML metadata file (*package.jdo*).

*"class"* entries in `persistence.xml` are to specify classes that have annotations, and you say you have none.

*"mapping-file"* entries in `persistence.xml` are to specify XML metadata files ... and you haven't specified any.